# How to run an artillery script with input variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, load-testing, artillery

```
artillery run my-script.yaml
```

In order to log into the `target`, a token must be used.

How do I run the above script with a token? IE:

```
artillery run my-script.yaml token 983r2fh29hf2893yr72
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the token must be provided to the API through, for example, a header. Artillery provides several mechanisms of doing that. If the token is static (i.e. you know the token ahead of time), then you can simply use an [inline variable](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/test-script#variables---inline-variables) in your test script to do that.

For example:

`my-script.yaml`

```yaml
config:
  target: "https://yourapi.com"
  phases:
    - duration: 1
      arrivalRate: 1
  variables:
    apiToken: 983r2fh29hf2893yr72 

scenarios:
  - flow:
      - get:
          url: "/"
          headers:
            Authorization: "Bearer {{ apiToken }}"
```

Then you simply run the script (i.e. `artillery run my-script.yaml`)

---

If the token is dynamic (for example you need to call an endpoint to authenticate and get a token before), then you might need to use a custom javascript function like a scenario hook: https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/engines/http#setting-scenario-level-hooks. Or, alternatively, a `before` which runs once before all scenarios (https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/test-script#before-and-after-sections).

But from your description, it sounds like the first example I gave is what you need.